# Google JS API not loading correctly anymore

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-javascript-api, google-api-client

for a long time I was using this

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js"></script>
```

In my program to make youtube queries and return results. That request is something I learned reading a different Stack question. But now when I load up my webpage I get these errors

[image: Errors]

and gapi is undefined when I try to search for a video (which is on button press). It is on this line

```
 gapi.client.setApiKey("MY KEY"); //gapi is undefined
```

It is hard to debug client.js because it is minimized. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Do you have a live example to look at?

Comment: The project is part of a research project and I can't present it right now but I can provide any code snippets you need.